# Spinning effect with only 2 images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

We only have 2 images of a bottle (front and back), but would like to create some kind of spinning effect. I was trying to think of some way of doing this with jquery or just CSS - maybe with blurring. Couldn't think of a good way.

They want to press a button to see the other side of the bottle (spinning to get there).

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [CSS Coke can](http://www.romancortes.com/blog/pure-css-coke-can/) example. That might help you get some quick results or at least serve as a base for new ideas. (English [here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/rolling-a-coke-can-around-with-pure-css), also it shows a little bit easier what's going on).
The only JS you'd need for this is to do the actual "scroll".

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, do that with the jQuery transit library http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('.bottle').transition({
    perspective: '100px',
    rotateY: '180deg'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Animate the width an margin left of the first image (front side) from `width: 300px; margin-left: 0px` to `width: 0px; margin-left: 150px`. Once the animation is complete, animate the second image from `width: 0px; margin-left: 150px` to `width: 300px; margin-left: 0px`.

You can use `.animate()` for this purpose: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

I hope this answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Check out demo 2 for the crossfade using a button. To get it to spin, add something like this:

```
transform:rotatey(180deg);
}
```